# Do while variables have to be in order? how can i do them when they are not in order?

Tags: c#

For example, when I have this code when my input is D then a F then a E. It pauses at D because it is at the bottom of the code. How can i make it when in any order they will all work?

```
while (response == "e" || response == "E")
{
  WriteLine ("Enter Line of sale");
  eamount = ReadLine();
  eamounti = Convert.ToDouble(eamount);
  esales = esales + eamounti;
  WriteLine ("Enter a salesperson initial");
response = ReadLine();
}


while (response == "f" || response == "F")
{
  WriteLine ("Enter Line of sale");
  famount = ReadLine();
  famounti = Convert.ToDouble(famount);
  fsales = fsales + famounti;
  WriteLine ("Enter a salesperson initial");
response = ReadLine();
}

while (response == "d" || response == "D")
{
  WriteLine ("Enter Line of sale");
  damount = ReadLine();
  damounti = Convert.ToDouble(damount);
  dsales = dsales + damounti;
  WriteLine ("Enter a salesperson initial");
response = ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Write a method that returns a boolean, accepts the response and based on if it's d,f or e, do the appropriate action, wrap the method in a do-while loop and if the method returns false (case when response is not d,f, or e) it exits the loop, else it keeps processing. I'll provide pseudo code as an answer if necessary.

Comment: You need to [step through your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour) and examine the variables at every step along the way. What you wrote and what you *think* you wrote are very different things. What's the value of `response` before any of this executes?

Comment: mad reflection.. the response has no value untill a user put input in there

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment, you could write a method which returns a boolean and wrap it in a do-while loop, this method would accept the response and process it based on the response type:

```
//private List<T> field of acceptable inputs for salesperson
private List<string> _acceptableInputs = new List<string> { "d", "D", "e", "E", "f", "F" };

 //Use a do-while, accepting input on first iteration and passing value to method
do
{
   WriteLine("Enter a salesperson initial");
   response = ReadLine();
}while(MyMethod(response)) //Method returns true/false, if it returns false it breaks loop

//Method to handle the processing of user input on valid input
//returns false if salesperson initial isn't found
//else tries to parse the next user input and add to appropriate
private bool MyMethod(string response)
{
   if(!_acceptableInputs.Contains(response))
     return false;
   
   string amount = "";
   double damount = 0.0;

   WriteLine("Enter Line of sale");
   amount = ReadLine();
   if(!Double.TryParse(amount, out damount)
      //throw exception 
     //or you can force them to do this in a loop until you get valid double
   
   switch(response)
   {
       case "d":
       case "D":
         //do something with d
         break;
       case "e":
       case "E":
         //do something with e
         break;
       case "f":
       case "F":
         //do something with f
         break;
   }
   
   return true;
}
```